# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't dettect my raid 0?

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, asus, raid, bios

This is a very unique situation that i never had before.

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a raid0 but the OS doesn’t detect the disks during the installation.) Anyone knows whats happen?

The raid was made on BIOS (ASUS TUF Z390-Pro Gamming and 2x Samsung 970 Evo Plus 500GB

Many thanks!